# What are my options for using a C++11 library in a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, wpf, c++11

I am writing a cross-platform (OS X and Windows) desktop application in C++11. I intend to use the same C++11 core on both platforms, utilizing native frameworks for the UI (Cocoa and Objective-C on OS X and WPF and C# on Windows) as I believe the best UX experience is a native one.

Currently the application runs as a console app on both platforms. The application performs some CPU-intensive work and provides callbacks for progress reporting and, when complete, instantiates a collection of Items (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`) representing the results of the processing.

My goal is for the C++11 library to act as a model for the UI in a manner compatible with the MVC and MVVM patterns.

The UI must:

- Allow the user to choose a file to process (open a file dialog and send the file path to the C++ library)
- Display progress (handle callbacks from the C++ library to update a progress bar)
- Display the results in a WPF form (access the Item class and display information it provides)

I've looked at WinRT and it seems there isn't a lot of information out there for use in desktop applications.  I'm also not fond of the idea of creating the UI itself in C++.  My goal is to get data in and out of the C++ app and use C# to handle the UI as I believe that's a more efficient way of working with WPF.

I'm aware of P/Invoke but my understanding is that it only works with a C interface. Creating such an interface around the C++11 seems cumbersome.

I'm also aware of C++/CLI but I'm not sure if that will meet my needs or if it is compatible with C++11.

I took a look at [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp) but it seems to be a work-in-progress and I doubt I'd know how to work around any issues that may arise.

I have a lot of experience with C++ and a little with C# but I'm not sure if I'm missing better options or which of the above is a sound approach.

Comment: You basically enumerated all the possibilities. The C++/CLI is supposed the be officially recommended way, but your requirement of C++11 makes it bad choice.

Comment: @Euphoric Could you expand on that? What are the problems with combing C++/CLI and C++11?

Comment: WinRT cannot be used to make desktop applications.

Comment: P/Invoke could potentially work for your particular situation even though you're using a C++ DLL. The only difference for C++ is that you have to specify the mangled DLL entry point names. You can get those by [using the dumpbin command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/653188/138757) in the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: I would just use http://xamarin.com/ and write one UI in C# for both Windows and iOS. The iOS version of xamarin is all native, but at least your using one toolkit.

Comment: I am also interested in more details regarding issues with C++/CLI and C++11.

Thanks @MathewFoscarini, but I am targeting OS X, not iOS and I have not had a good experience with Xamarin on the Mac.

Comment: @Ramhound: correction, WinRT can only be used to make desktop applications if you're Microsoft. There is a jailbreak, but I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @david.pfx - Your statement is false.  Office 2013 RT isn't a Windows Runtime desktop application.  Even Microsoft can't make a WinRT desktop application.  I think you meant to say that only Microsoft can make a desktop Windows RT application which is true.  **WinRT and Windows RT is two ENTIRELY DIFFERENT THINGS**

Comment: @Ramhound: If by WinRT you mean the Windows Runtime, then while it's not possible for a desktop application to be built using only WinRT APIs (since it has to interact with the desktop), it can still use many of them. The available set is larger for Microsoft than others, so there are desktop applications targeting WinRT that Microsoft can build and others can't.

If by WinRT you mean Windows RT, then it is completely possible to build applications using only Win32 APIs on this OS. Microsoft can do it, and others can't. Perhaps we are in furious agreement.

Comment: @david.pfx - I don't understand your confusion. I clearly understand that WinRT is the **Windows Runtime** which is different from the `Win32 Library` which is used non-Java x86-64 Windows applications. My statement is correct you **cannot** make a Windows Desktop x86-x64 application by using references to the `WinRT` and `Win32` at the sametime.  I have been a .NET/Win32 Developer for 10 years.

Comment: Hmm, turns out the C++11 libraries `<thread>` and `<atomic>` are not supported in CLI.  I'm using both of those. :/

Comment: @Ramhound: as it happens, I've been a .NET/Win32 programmer for 14/22 years respectively. You can indeed make a Windows desktop application that uses the WinRT and Win32 API at the same time. Ask a question and you might find out how.

Comment: @david.pfx - Thats alright; We went really offtopic. I can answer my own questions. Looks like you are indeed [right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications.aspx) I also realize I was off on the amount of time I have been working with .NET. I actually started using VB.NET in early 2000 during the beta of `Visual Studio .NET`

Comment: @Ramhound: PDC bits in 2000, VS.Net too unstable so command line C#, plus accessing the underside of the CLR in COM. WinRT is COM so WRL is like an old friend, except for the MS restrictions. I was going to suggest it to the OP, but probably wouldn't suit his purposes.

Comment: @david.pfx - The best professor in college gave us access to the PBC clients to VS.NET.  He is the reason I hav spend the last 13 years trying to master it.

Comment: It seems to me there is simply much more documentation and information available for WPF in C#. While WinRT is intriguing, I'm looking to support Windows 7 as well and truly believe C# is the way to go.  Thanks for the interesting discussion.

Answer (score 2):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can generate [C# wrappers](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/CSharp.html#CSharp) for C++ code.  I have no experience using it for this, so I don't know how well it works.

I believe the current release of SWIG (version 2.x) has at least some C++11 support, but you may need to use the [development version](https://github.com/swig/swig) for full support.

Answer (score 1):

A part of an answer...

Most times in the solution to this problem you will finish up with 3 layers.

1. A native C/C++ layer, that can call the Windows API or COM or C++ libraries
2. A managed C/C++ layer, that can access the C# object model and framework
3. A C# layer, because it's easier to actually use the .NET Framework and WPF in C#.

P/Invoke refers to the calls between native and managed code, but in this kind of structure they kind of happen inside layer (2). Layer (2) used to be Managed C++ but is now replaced by C++/CLI. Each of the layers can talk to the one next to it easily, but (1) does not easily talk to (3) or vice versa.

You may find a product that just does exactly what you want, but I don't know one. More likely you will have to write what you need with this kind of layered structure.

I've done this 3+ times with 3+ different generations of Managed C/C++, and we have a commercial product built this way (legacy C/C++ <=> ASP.NET/remoting). Each generation the managed layer is different but the overall structure has stayed the same. [edit]

I suggest: write some code, but plan to throw it away. Experimentation is in order.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I'd have to maintain (1) and (3) but am curious about my options for (2). I plan to write a prototype using C++/CLI for (2) and see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: See edit. I would be remiss not to point out that it is possible to build very rich native UIs on Windows without going anywhere near the .NET framework. All the legacy controls use the old USER API, and most of the new (Aero and DirectX) stuff can be accessed through COM. There are frameworks like WTL and tons of support. Just a thought -- definitely not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What is a native UI on Windows any more? WPF doesn't look 'standard', winforms and MFC are dead, like Silverlight. It could be said the most native of apps are now HTML, especially if you're writing Windows8 tiles.

So my suggestion would be to use [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) which uses native controls to render. Your UI will look like a traditional Windows program rather than a "Modern" one, but that's what you were after isn't it?

If you do still need to use WPF for the GUI, you can write a C++/CLI interface wrapper that calls your C++ dll, or you could expose your dll as a service and let the WPF make socket (or other RPC) calls into it. If its very chatty, this would not be the best solution, but if it makes few, long-running calls then its ideal. A service would also be the best solution to bind a web front-end to your dll as well, though I'd expose the service as a [WWS web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335693.aspx) in this case.

Comment: Considering unthemed WPF looks exactly like built in Microsoft applications like File Explorer, saying it doesn't look 'standard' is rather incorrect.

Comment: @Magus I partly meant that every WPF app I've seen has been skinned into something horrid, but also partly because there is no standard Windows app anymore - toolbars are different, or ribboned; colour schemes and either blue/silver or eye-burning white/white/grey or there's funny control bar-style toolbar/menubars/statusbars.. Do you want a file menu, or an orb-style menu thing; is there a property page or a funny looking screen of large buttons. Nothing is consistent anymore.

Comment: Except if you use WPF, which matches your theme. The ribbon thing, sure. I'll buy that. Theming WPF is usually a bad idea, but don't blame the tool for its misuse. You can only do that to php, vb, and winforms.

Comment: I actually have a lot of experience with wxWidgets and in part, that's what led me to decide to use a fully native solution. The last time I checked, the Ribbon control in wxWidgets was too different from the native solution to be useful in my opinion.